# Difference between Django validate and a validator

Tags: python, django, validation, field

From the Django docs 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/

> The validate() method on a Field handles field-specific validation that is not suitable for a validator.

This implies that `validate()` is different than a validator.  What is the difference?

I'm curious because I'm using a custom validate on a custom form field. It raises a `ValidationError`, but the code keeps running and calls Django's validate and clean afterwords and doesn't do anything with the `ValidationError` that I raised.  This is not the case with my custom validators.  When those raise errors, they are added to the errors field on the form.  Is this expected behavior?

Comment: You should post your code here regarding question

Comment: I don't believe that this is specific to my code.  I am referencing the documentation to understand if I am missing something such as how Django handles validate() versus a validator.  Does it go through the same steps or different steps? Are the errors of one caught but not the other?  These are general Django questions that I would like to know the answer to, regardless of what my code is.